# C# Magic Wand Tool

Tags: c#, image-processing

I want to write a function that work like magic wand tool  dynamic in C# .
Can I do ?
Thanks

Comment: "magic wand tool"? Which magic wand tool? I didn't know C# had a magic wand tool...

Answer (score 10):

You basically need flood fill algorithm.

Use this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/floodfillincsharp.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/queuelinearfloodfill.aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill